# Form I/O in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, io

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am having a hard time wrapping my head around form input/output and form handling.

I am trying to incorporate a form input for a website (url) as an input for my 'New Project' form and trying to display that link on another view.

Here is the code from my partial (front-end/view):

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
```

.
.
.

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :website %><br>
<%= f.text_field :website, :class => "form-control"%>
</div>
```

Code from my controller:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
```

.
.

```
:website,
)
end
```

Everytime I try to test this, it gives me a **NoMethodError** on the form itself. But it does not do that for any other field of the form.

Am I missing something here? Am I supposed to add something to the model? Or generate something via the command line?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you created a `Project` model and does it have a `website` field? You can verify in `db/schema.rb`

Comment: try read the error message, it will not be your last.... What exactly throw the NoMethodError, what method is it that was not found? When you go up the Stracktrace, do you find any lines from your code?

Comment: @Meier I do find the lines from my code that are giving me the error; the declaration of the website field in the .erb file. Then the second error on the  'form_for' declaration. But the second error goes away once I comment out the website declaration code.

Comment: @omarshammas I do have a 'Project' model, but I do not have a `website` field. I believe that the model only has such fields for validation, no? I will check `db/schema.rb` right away. Thank you for your response

Comment: @Meier, I get `undefined method `website' for #<Project`

Comment: Does the project schema has a "website" field? double check the spelling.

Comment: @Meier I added `t.text   "website"` under the `create_table "projects"` in `db/schema.rb` manually. Still I get the same error.

Comment: So it was not there? => You found your error. Now read the Basic Guide about Rails and Database: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html